# Is it correct to keep the ids of different related tables in the database?

Tags: relational-database

I have two different entities for employees and managers, but they have one common attribute, in the announcements table is it right even if I did not send any announcement to the employee or manager?

[image]

Comment: It depends what the announcement table is intended for! It is impossible to say if a particular database structure is fit for purpose without knowing the purpose and you did not share any details as to what the announcement table is for and what the manager and employee fields represent there. Not to mention the fact that the managers are also employees, so storing them in a separate table is not particularly a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,it is actually quite common.

What you got is a bridge table between employee and manager, and you added necessary column to the table, which enhance the bridge table.

If there is no relation ship between employee and manager, if you doun't sed announcement, then ther is no entry in the bridge table, you can chekc i the table if an employee never got such an announcement or how many he got

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am actually confused about the bridge table, there is no exact relationship between employee and manager in terms of the announcement.

Comment: if you enter a row in renouncement and enter an id for manager and emploee then you create a relations between both tables. Your image is a example for bridge tables. bridge are used to program n_m relathionhsips 1 manager can have multiple employees for example